# AWS REST API lambda function integration for webhook

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

If a user make any changes on the client site , it notifies whoever is listening via webhook. The client site has the feature of inputing a webhook URL , it should be a REST API. Earlier for testing, I made a simple script using express:

app.post('/', (req, res) => {

```
console.log(req.body);
res.status(200).send('EVENT_RECEIVED');
```

});

I used ngrok to make it publicly accessible , it created a link that worked as webhook. So whenever I made any changes on the client website from my account. It showed, all the data on my terminal which was running app.post method.

I want to do something similar in AWS. So far, I have able to create REST API endpoint. And I have set this endpoint to the website, the website sure does hit the endpoint whenever I make any changes, But I am not sure how to output something like res.body. Or, whether I should link to lambda function or another API endpoint.

At the end , I just want to make a webhook URL that will listen for changes, and it should output req.body via AWS.

Thanks!

Comment: do you mean you want to deploy your service on AWS and have this client hit that service? Which part is the challenge?

Comment: I am really new to AWS, I want to deploy this service, and whenever there is a change on client website, The client sends request body in which there is email. So I want to use req.body.email, and send email to the user.

Comment: So I'm imagining this as a web application where the user will a) write an email, b) specify the webhook url. My question is - is this webhook url ever going to change? i think not.

Comment: Nope the webhook url will never change, actually the webhook url is the REST API which uses a post method, that part I have created. It sure does hit the endpoint, but I am not sure how to get the data sent by the client website. As I described earlier, I used req.body and it had the data. But now, I am not sure what to link the REST API to ? perhaps a lambda function, that is my guess. Not sure what to write inside the lambda function that will output the data.

Comment: so, the client needs to hit a POST REST api -- google this based on what tech you're using on the cient, you'll find an implementation that works easily.

Comment: Now AWS lambda is simply a way of deploying on AWS - does not have anything to do with your service itself. Irrespective of what kind of deployment you pick, the console log will be printed on the server itself so you'll have no access to it (unless you're ssh ing into machines -this won't work with lambda). Where do you want this data to be for you to look at it?